# printing instance data using static properties

Tags: c#

I've written some list of classes, here's the code I used to initialize class

```
  public class Album
   {
       static public int IDNumber { get; set; }
       static public string AlbumName { get; set; }
       static public string Artist { get; set; }
       static public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
       static public int TrackAmount { get; set; }
       static public string Location { get; set; }
       static public int Rating { get; set; }

       public Album(int _id, string _name, string _artist, int _releasedate, int _trackamount, string _location, int _rating)
       {
           IDNumber = _id;
           AlbumName = _name;
           Artist = _artist;
           ReleaseDate = _releasedate;
           TrackAmount = _trackamount;
           Location = _location;
           Rating = _rating;
       }
   }
```

I add everything from console like that:

```
   static private List<Album> AlbumsList = new List<Album>();
   public void addnew()
   { 
       //getting from console to separate variables with names below in .add method
       AlbumsList.Add(new Album(ID, AlbNm, Art, RelD, TrAmn, Loc, Rat));  
       currid++;
   }
```

I also added printing code:

```
   static public void printlist(List<Album>AlbumsList)
   {
       foreach (Album IDNumber in AlbumsList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(Album.IDNumber + Album.AlbumName + Album.Artist + Album.ReleaseDate + Album.TrackAmount + Album.Location + Album.Rating);
       }
   }
```

Unfortunately it displays last "album" as many times as many different albums I have. Can anyone help me?

Comment: static values and functions are shared. Make all your variables and methods non-static, and change your calling code to refer to IDNumber instead of Album

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your properties are *static* - that means that they are related to the type rather than any one instance of the type. (It's not that the values are "shared by all instance" - it's that they're completely unrelated to *any* instance.)

You should make them *instance* properties instead, just by removing the `static` modifier. You'll then need to change your `foreach` loop as well. Notice how in your current `foreach` loop you're completely ignoring your loop variable (`IDNumber`)? That's a hint that something's wrong. Try this instead:

```
// Variable and method names changed to be more readable and conventional.
// Modifier order also changed for convention.
public static void PrintList(List<Album> albums)
{
    foreach (Album album in albums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(album.IDNumber + album.AlbumName + album.Artist + 
                          album.ReleaseDate + album.TrackAmount + album.Location + 
                          album.Rating);
    }
}
```

Or rather more pleasantly:

```
static public void PrintList(List<Album> albums)
{
    foreach (Album album in albums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}",
                          album.IDNumber, album.AlbumName, album.Artist,
                          album.ReleaseDate, album.TrackAmount, album.Location,
                          album.Rating);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All your properties are static. That means that all instances of your `Album` class share the same values accross those properties. Because of this, when you initialize album properties, you're simply overwriting the same set of properties in every album, so you end up with the last values assigned to those properties: this is why your loop prints out the last values.

You need to remove the `static` keyword from the property declarations so the properties become instance-specific: two `Album` objects can have different names that way.

Your `foreach` loop is also broken and will have to be fixed. You're using `Album.AlbumName` at the moment but once you make the `AlbumName` property instance-specific (non-static), that won't work anymore - you have to access each property through an instance, not through the class that declares it.

Your `foreach` loop should be something like:

```
foreach (Album album in albumList)
{
    Console.WriteLine ( album.IDNumber + ", " + album.AlbumName + ... );
}
```

Notice how the code is using the `album` instance variable to access the album properties, rather than the `Album` class.

Comment: Then I get an error : Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.BazaDanych.Album.AlbumName.get' C:\Users\Eziush\Desktop\C++ Programy\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\BazaDanych.cs 136

Comment: See my comment on Servy's answer - describing static members as shared between "all instances" suggests that they have something to do with those instances.

Comment: @user3658127 Yes, because in your loop, you're using `Album.IDNumber`. What you should use is (at the moment) `IDNumber.AlbumName`.

Comment: @user3658127 You should consider renaming the `IDNumber` variable to `currentAlbum` for clarity in your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

All of your properties are static, that means that the state is shared among every single instance of the class.  All of the properties of `Album` should be non-static.  When accessing the properties to print them out you should be accessing them through the instance of `Album` that you have (you called it `IDNumber`, which, for the record, is a bad name for an album) rather than through the type itself.

Comment: It's not that the state is shared among every instance - it's that it's completely *independent* of instances. It doesn't matter if there's never a single instance created.

Comment: @JonSkeet The set of all instances can be an empty set, and the statement still applies.  I don't see a difference between the two statements.

Comment: But with an empty set, it sounds silly IMO. The instances are just irrelevant - the members aren't associated with instances at all. You might just as easliy have said "That means that the state is shared among every integer" - it's just as correct as saying it's shared among every instance of the class. I think it's important to distinguish between instances and "the type itself" - which is what the state is really associated with.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's just it, information shared between *all* instances of a type is information stored independently by the type itself.  Both conceptualizations have all of the same implications, it simply comes down to which is easier to understand.  I find that users grasp, "shared between all instances" more easily than "information specific to the type itself".

Comment: They may grasp some of it, but I suspect they'll be left with the feeling that it does have something to do with the instances - after all, you mentioned them, so they must be important in the concept. Why bring them in at all, when they're completely irrelevant? Would you say that my statement of "the state is shared among every single integer" or perhaps "the state is shared among every single `InputStream`" is equally correct? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: @JonSkeet I wouldn't say that those statements are *wrong*.  I simply find that when you say, "That information is a property of the type itself," the most common response is, "What does that even mean?" rather than, "Oh, now I get it."

Comment: I'd rather have to explain a bit further than leave an erroneous impression that the static state had *anything* to do with any instances that happen to have been created. They're irrelevant to the state, so why link them in people's minds at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet Because it's easier for many people to understand, and I can't think of any real incorrect implications of beginning with that model.  If there were particularly harmful implications of that model, then sure, I could understand the problem, but I don't see any.

Comment: I just always find it easier to start with a correct model than have to go via two or three of them. I agree that this case is much less harmful than other "simplifications" such as "objects are passed by reference" but I'd rather not set up the connection between instances and static state in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

All your properties are static.

You are updating the values of the static properties in your constructor.

```
public class Album
   {
       public int IDNumber { get; set; }
       public string AlbumName { get; set; }
       public string Artist { get; set; }
       public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
       public int TrackAmount { get; set; }
       public string Location { get; set; }
       public int Rating { get; set; }

       public Album(int _id, string _name, string _artist, int _releasedate, int _trackamount, string _location, int _rating)
       {
           IDNumber = _id;
           AlbumName = _name;
           Artist = _artist;
           ReleaseDate = _releasedate;
           TrackAmount = _trackamount;
           Location = _location;
           Rating = _rating;
       }
   }
```

Also, in your `foreach` loop, you are printing the static properties. You need to print the values of the instance that you are iterating through.

```
   static public void printlist(List<Album>AlbumsList)
   {
       foreach (Album alb AlbumsList)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(alb.IDNumber + alb.AlbumName + alb.Artist + alb.ReleaseDate + alb.TrackAmount + alb.Location + alb.Rating);
       }
   }
```